# json value returned from a promise does not give node values when using React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, promise

My promise returns the response object that looks like the following:

```
Response:
Person: Array(3)
0: {Name: 'PersonA', Data: Array(2)}
1: {Name: 'PersonB', Data: Array(3)}
2: {Name: 'PersonC', Data: Array(4)}
```

This is the function used to fetch the response

```js
public personData = (): Promise<any> => {
    const personData = `http://url/get/someperson/data/personData.json`;
    return (
      fetch(personData , { method: "GET" })
        .then((response) =>
          response.json().then((response) => ({
            response,
          }))
        )
        .catch((e) => console.log(e))
    );
  };
```

However, I want to fetch all the Person names and populate them to a drop-down list. However, I'd first just like to fetch all the values of Person name and populate them into a variable.

To do this, if I try something like this val is always **undefined**

```
const val = personData().then((personNames: any): void => {
      (personNames.Person);
});
```

With my limited understanding, any advice or guidance on resolving this issue is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you doing in your `val` function? In the `then` block? It is merely an expression did you wanted to return it? `.then((personNames) => personNames.Person);`

Comment: Yes, what I'm trying to do here is basically fetch all the Person name values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is what I had to do to get the person name values.

```
const getPersonVal = async (): Promise<void> => {
   const personVal = await getData();
   console.log(personVal.response.Person.map((personName: any) => personName.Name));
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are getting the function name wrong. It should be `getData` and not `personData`.

Also, if you want to return the value assigned to the variable `val`, you could try:

```
const val = await getData();
```

OR if you still want to use `then/catch`:

```
let val;
getData().then((personNames: any) =>
  {
    val = personNames.Person; // should assign the value there
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**
Sorry, I missed the return type possibilities. The catch case returns just void type that doesn't have map. So I just put the value setting subsequently. I assume response is list.

```
let val

const getData = () => {
  const personData = `http://url/get/someperson/data/personData.json`;
  return fetch(personData, { method: 'GET' })
    .then((response) =>
      response.json().then((response) => {
        val = response.map((person: any) => person.Name)
      })
    )
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);
    });
};
```

=============================
I updated your code. You should modify the response and return it.

```
const val = getData().then((personList: any): [] => {
  return personList.map((person: any) => person.Name);
});

OR one liner expression below

const val = getData().then((personList: any): []=>  personList.map((person: any) => person.Name);
    );
```

Comment: It seems like for some reason I can't use .map() here.

It gives me a Type error:
TypeError: personList.map is not a function

Comment: I've updated my answer. Could you try this?